# Suspend a running task then resume it AFTER a system restart

Tags: windows, tasks

Is it possible to suspend a Windows task and then resume it after a system restart? It should be possible, right? If it is, how can I do it? Any programs that offer this?

[Example of a program that can suspend and then resume tasks, however this program cannot resume a program after a system restart which is what I want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0eD5.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry mate, that is not possible. If you restart windows all information in RAM is lost. To continue a task is only possible in suspend to disk modes, where information is stored on the hdd/ssd and loaded back to memory on resume, with all programms running.

The program you are refering to does only pause the execution of the task. All its memory information is reserved.

A possible solution would be to run your task within a virtual machine. You could pause the VM, reboot your windows, and resume the VM after your hosting Windows is back up and running.

Comment: Ah. :/ I hoped it was some way to suspend a single task to the disk and then resume that single task after a reboot.